# Adding MenuItems to the Shell from Modules

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, modularity

My shell has a `Menu` which defines a `MenuRegion`.
`Menu` is an `ItemsControl` so it can contain `MenuItem`s (of course).

I try to make views (`UserControl`) in my modules containing `MenuItem`s and add them to the `MenuRegion` by e.g.

```
regionManager.Regions["MenuRegion"].Add(theUserControlContainingMenuItems)
```

But this creates another `Menu` instance behind the scene which creates problems.

What is the recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you create and `UserControl`s to the `Menu` instead of `MenuItem`s. It is the same behavior for all `ItemsControl`s, if you add an item that is not of the container type of that specific control (e.g. `ListViewItem` in a `ListView`), the item will be wrapped in a container automatically.

Let us assume, you have defined the menu region like this.

```
<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static regions:RegionNames.Menu}"/>
```

Since Visual Studio does not offer a template to add a new `MenuItem`, create a `UserControl`, and change the contents of the XAML and code-behind files like this.

Contents of *FileMenuItem.xaml.cs*:

```
<MenuItem x:Class="Example.FileMenuItem"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
          xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
          xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
          prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
          mc:Ignorable="d"
          Header="File">
   <MenuItem Header="New"/>
   <MenuItem Header="Open"/>
   <MenuItem Header="Save"/>
</MenuItem>
```

Contents of *FileMenuItem.cs*:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Example
{
   public partial class FileMenuItem : MenuItem
   {
      static FileMenuItem()
      {
      }

      public FileMenuItem()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }
   }
}
```

Create these files for each of your menu items and the following will work.

```
regionManager.Regions["MenuRegion"].Add(new FileMenuItem());
```